# Heroku postbuild script not building client

Tags: node.js, npm, heroku

I'm trying to deploy a nodejs app with a react client folder on heroku. I have a heroku-postbuild script that's supposed cd into client and install dependencies and then build.

I've verified that this works perfectly if done manually via terminal, but for some reason when I push to heroku, the client folder never seems to actually be built.

Here's the log output:

```
Installing dependencies
remote:        Installing node modules (package.json)
remote:        audited 216 packages in 0.969s
remote:        
remote:        21 packages are looking for funding
remote:          run `npm fund` for details
remote:
remote:        found 0 vulnerabilities
remote:
remote:
remote: -----> Build
remote:        Running heroku-postbuild
remote:        
remote:        > chessalong2api@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild 
/tmp/build_dk354b8k
remote:        > cd chessalong2 && npm install && npm run build  
remote:
remote:        audited 216 packages in 1.083s
remote:        
remote:        21 packages are looking for funding
remote:          run `npm fund` for details
remote:
remote:        found 0 vulnerabilities
```

Why is that the number of node modules installed is the same before and after the cd into the client? I'm interpreting this as heroku not being able to enter the client folder ("chessalong2" is the name of the client folder"). What could be going wrong?

Comment: Same issue her. Did you have some solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Have you added a client folder in git changes ??

Comment: how would I do that? I did definitely add and commit all files before pushing

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).